# HammerJs : singletap and doubletap not detected

Tags: javascript, tap

When setup your own set of recognizers as

```
buildHammer(element: HTMLElement): HammerInstance {
  let mc = new Hammer(element, { domEvents: true });
  let doubleTap = new Hammer.Tap({
    event: "doubletap",
    taps: 2
  });
  let singleTap = new Hammer.Tap({ event: "singletap" });
  mc.add([singleTap, doubleTap]);
  doubleTap.recognizeWith(singleTap);
  singleTap.requireFailure(doubleTap);

  mc.on("doubleTap", function(e) {
    console.log("double tap");
  });

  mc.on("singleTap", function(e) {
    console.log("single tap");
  });

  return mc;
```

}

The events are not fired when they are attached with the HTML element

```
<div (doubleTap)="onDoubleTap($event)" (singleTap)="onSingleTap($event)">
```

However works fine if I use hammerjs recognizer "tap" as

```
<div (tap)="onTap($event)">
```

and use event.tapCount

Is there any thing I am doing wrong with the previous one?

Comment: I love how everyone uses `mc` as the variable name. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @zfrisch : no errors

Comment: @zfrisch is mc a convention?

Comment: @VineyHill no, haha. Google MC Hammer

Comment: still waiting for the right answer please